# Не могу установить PyAudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

Я скачиваю с официального сайта, но выдает ошибку после ввода в командную строку это команду `pip install PyAudio`
 Выдает ошибку:

> `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qtd2ych9\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qtd2ych9\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tsdhdmar\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio' cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qtd2ych9\PyAudio\ Complete output (15 lines): running install running build running build_py creating build creating build\lib.win32-3.8 copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8 running build_ext building '_portaudio' extension creating build\temp.win32-3.8 creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj _portaudiomodule.c src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory, error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`
>   `---------------------------------------- 
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qtd2ych9\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qtd2ych9\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tsdhdmar\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.`

Что делать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну там же прямо написано - требуется Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, установите для этого "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools", взять их можно по по ссылке https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Надеюсь поможет :)  Некоторые пакеты приходят готовыми, а некоторые при сборке компилируются на целевой машине, это вот такой случай, когда идёт компиляция при сборке. Но под виндой не всегда всё проходит хорошо, могут быть и потом сложности

Comment: Я не понял что именно надо скачать Visual Studio 2019 или Visual Studio Code

Comment: Да, это не элементарно, я смотрю. Вот такой линк нашёл в одном из ответов: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.
Можете другие варианты ответов и комментариев ещё там посмотреть, если не получится с этим линком всё: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: Ещё такой линк сам на той странице загрузки нашёл: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/7/5F7ACAEB-8363-451F-9425-68A90F98B238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe Судя по размеру это тот же файл, но линк другой

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Всё равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Перейди [сюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), скачай уже собранный wheel (тебе будет нужен  `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`), после установи его с диска: `pip install Downloads\PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`, готово.